# Bootstrap modal: dynamically load value in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap modal in a Laravel app that I'm trying to dynamically load. The idea is to fill the input fields in the modal with data coming from my database so I can update the values. I'm almost there....

I have the following in my view file:

```
   <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-auction-modal" data-id="1" data-title="title 1" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-warning">Open modal</a>
```

The 'data-id' and 'data-title' are passed to a JS function that looks as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('#edit-auction-modal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
         $("#auctionLabel").html('Edit auction with id '+ $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
         $("#auctionTitle").html($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'));
    });
});
```

This JS function captures the id and title successfully. In the below modal view, I can print out the id in the panel-title because I'm telling in JS to put the data in the id="auctionLabel".

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="edit-auction-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title" id="auctionLabel"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body edit-content" style="padding-top:10px">
                     <form  method="POST" action="{!! route('admin_auctions_update') !!}">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="auction_name" class="control-label">Auction name</label>
                        <input name="auction_name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Auction name" value="{{$auction->auction_name}}">
                      </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update auction</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is how I need to change the Javascript function in order to pre-fill the input fields with the value of the title. In other words, I want the value of the input box to contain the 'title' that I captured in the JS file.

Comment: `<input name="auction_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Auction name" value="{{$auction->auction_name}}">` .Do you want to change this value?

Comment: Yes, I want to prefill that input field with the value I retrieve in Javascript. Note, there are more than 1 input fields in reality

Comment: `$('#edit-auction-modal ').find('input#youid').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'))` would solve the problem for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#edit-auction-modal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
     $("#auctionLabel").html('Edit auction with id '+ $(e.relatedTarget).data('id'));
     $("#auctionTitle").html($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'));
    $('#edit-auction-modal ').find('input#input-id').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'))
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact there are more input fields, so I would like to find a input field based on the id or name. Is this possible? I tried myself: document.getElementById("name").value = ($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'));

Comment: pass id to input like this:

$('#edit-auction-modal ').find('input#input-id').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'))

Comment: OK thanks. That works. Would you please edit your answer with the above suggestion so I can accept it for other people to clearly see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.val( value )` to set/change the input value in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2