# Sending one more value via POST PHP

Tags: php, html

It's my first post so welcome!

I'm struggling with one problem in my project. As you can see at my screenshot, i have few names which are fetched from database, and displayed in main menu. after clicking "modal" button, modal from bootstrap is showed with php form. user can type a 4 digit pin code, next step is to match this pin with database records. But 2 users can have same pin so i need to compare not only pin with database, but name too. i don`t know how to send "name" value with post. Here is my code and screenshot:

index.php:

```
  <?php 
 $data = $worker->select_workers();
$worker->show_workers($data);
$worker->show_modal();
```

worker.php:

```
<?php 
require_once('db.php');
class Worker extends db {

protected $select_workers;
    public function select_workers(){

                return $this->select_workers = $this->query('SELECT * FROM worker')->fetchAll();
    }

    public function show_workers($data){
        foreach ($data as $users) {
    echo '<p id="p_name">'.$users['name'].'</p><a id="button_modal" href="/?name='.$users['name'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Modal
</a><br>';

}
}
    public function show_modal(){
echo '<!-- Button trigger modal -->


<!-- Modal -->
<form action="test.php" id="submit_ajax" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal_title" name="name"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="hidden_name" type="text" value="" name="name" />
Hasło:<input type="text" name="password"><br>



      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Przerwa/powrót</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
    }
```

[Main menu of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YB67.png)

I belive that solution is really simple but like always - i waste too many times for complicated things which are not working. Sorry for my english, it's not my native language :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put value here `<input id="hidden_name" type="text" value="<?= $name ?>" name="name" />`, but if you fetch data from db, isn't it better to use ids instead of names?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I will change it on ID later. Your answer would be good if i had modals for every displayed user. I have one modal, and i want do make it dynamic.

Comment: if you want to make it dynamic, you must change the value of name-input with jquery. on show the modal.

Comment: put data-user-id attibute in modal trigger button and take it with jquery when it's clicked

Comment: <a id="button_modal" data-user-id="'.$users['id'].'" href="/?name='.$users['name'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Modal
</a>

Also you need to remove ids or make them unique like this id="button_modal'. $users['id']  '"

Comment: @RubenDanielyan 
 `$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#password_input').trigger('focus');
  var val = $('p#p_name').html();
  $('#hidden_name').prop('name',val)
})`

Value of name always shows first name.

Comment: @RubenDanielyan Ohh nevermind. I got this. Your answer was the best! ;)

Comment: That's fine) Then you can mark the answer as right one

Comment: @RubenDanielyan Actually.. i was happy too fast. When i click on modal, okey - my hidden input got update with "name" property. But i always have only "1" value. I can't get other id's like "7", "3" or "2". How script can identify which button was actually clicked?

` $('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#password_input').trigger('focus');
  var val = $('#button_modal').attr('data-user-id');
  $('#hidden_name').prop('name',val)
})

Comment: let me add another answer, one moment

Comment: Sorry i can't provide full code to help you, either provide you buttons code or do so, give the same class to all buttons that trigger modal, then listen to the class click
```$('.modal-trigger-btn').click(function(){
     let val = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
     $('#hidden_name').prop('name',val);
     $('#exampleModal').modal();
})```

Comment: @RubenDanielyan 
I figured out solution using event object. But thank you very much :) 

 `$('input[type=button]').click(function (e) {
  $('#password_input').trigger('focus');
  var val = e.target.id;
  $('#hidden_name').prop('name',val)
})`

Comment: I suggested that above) but i am happy you could figure it out by yourself. Good luck in your project)

Answer (score 0):

Not clean solution. make for every worker a modal.

```
<?php 
require_once('db.php');
class Worker extends db {

protected $select_workers;
    public function select_workers(){

                return $this->select_workers = $this->query('SELECT * FROM worker')->fetchAll();
    }

    public function show_workers($data){
        $i=0;
        foreach ($data as $users) {
        $i++;
    echo '<p id="p_name">'.$users['name'].'</p><a id="button_modal" href="/?name='.$users['name'].'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal'.$i.'">
  Modal
</a><br>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->


<!-- Modal -->
<form action="test.php" id="submit_ajax" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal'.$i.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal_title" name="name"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input id="hidden_name" type="text" value="'.$users['name'].'" name="name" />
Hasło:<input type="text" name="password"><br>



      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Przerwa/powrót</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Ohh. It seems as solution of my problem, but i lost concept of my dynamic modal.

Comment: look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38221097/4173464